# reasoning behind the constraints on when you can call a static method in a class definition

Tags: java, static, static-methods, static-members, initializer

Why must a static method, if called in a class definition, be called within a static initializer block unless you are assigning the output to a variable.

```
public class MyClass {
  int a = staticFunction(); // Allowed.

  static int b = staticFunction(); // Allowed.

  staticFunction(); // Not allowed!

  static  {
    staticFunction(); // Allowed.
  }

  private static int staticFunction() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

I am guessing it is because the JVM does not know if this method should be called once when the class is loaded, or every time an object is created.

Comment: Because you can't invoke a method without giving it some sort of context to invoke it in, whether this is a variable assignment, an initializer block, another method, a constructor, etc.

Comment: This has nothing to do with static methods.

Comment: In the end, the answer is simply "because that's the rules of Java syntax." Another language might do it differently. This isn't another language.

Comment: Being able to invoke a method to initialize a variable outside of `static` or a constructor is a compiler swizzle.  In reality the method is invoked in the `static` or constructor method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the JVM does not know if this method should be called once when the class is loaded (statically), or every time an object is created (per instance).

Therefore, calling this static method must be done in an initializer, be it a static initializer or instance initializer.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be called in a *static* initializer block; it can be called in an instance initializer too, which looks just like a static initializer block but without the word `static`:

```
public class MyClass {

  staticFunction(); // Not allowed!

  {
    staticFunction(); // Allowed.
  }

  private static int staticFunction() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

The instance initializer is called any time you create a new `MyClass` object.  (It's usually clearer if you put something like that in a constructor, which has about the same effect.  But instance initializers can be useful for anonymous classes where you can't write your own constructor.)

Comment: I have read about the horrors called *instance initializers* before, and I'd still like to see a good usecase for them. Could you show one about the anonymous classes you mention?

Comment: @skiwi Flanagan had one in his _Java in a Nutshell_ but I don't have the book handy.  I've been trying to look for a good example on the web--maybe http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization ?  I don't think I've personally ever used it.